# Forcing overflow to top instead of bottom

Tags: html, css

I would like my content to overflow to the top and left instead of the bottom right in a div.

The purpose is that when expanding the div it looks like the content is coming in from the top instead from the bottom.

Is there any way to do this is CSS? Much like the way you set `vertical-align` for text, I would like to have the div overflow to the top instead of the bottom

Comment: I don't exactly want the content to rotate~ Just to set the direction it overflows (*Like setting text to align to the right vs left*)

Answer (score 7):

Something like this would do the trick.

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8P3g/1/)**</kbd>

***HTML***

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overflow"></div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #eee;
}

.wrapper .overflow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
}
```