# How to get a row in a grid layout to overflow out the top instead of out of the bottom

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've been struggling to make a two-column, three row, layout, where the middle row should (almost always - see 3rd example below) be fixed vertically. I almost had it working with good old tables, but the middle row moved up/down if the amount of content in top/bottom rows was not balanced. This appears to be a fundamental limit of tables, so I've switched to trying to get it working with grid. And I am quite close with this:

https://codepen.io/ddd2347823457823782378/pen/OJLvMXO

The problem is that the `overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom` are not working together. I.e. it shows the start of the content, when it should be showing the end, and cutting off at the top.

Or (replying to comment), if the scrollbar was visible on those top two cells, I expect the scroll position to be at the bottom, not at the top.

EDIT: Just to add, in case it suggests a different solution to anyone: the content of the `before` and `after` rows is likely to change from being one long block of text, into a nested two-column table (or sub-grid).  E.g. there are, say, 10 rows to show in `before`, and the goal is to show as many of those rows as will fit. (And the same for the `after`.)

BTW, the following one (only the amount of text has been modified) shows the desirable behaviour, which is that the middle paragraph stays at the same place, even if not much content in the top row. (It does have the problem that the textarea has a scrollbar, and I want it to just stretch its div instead.)

https://codepen.io/ddd2347823457823782378/pen/JjPLGRY

Finally, this (again just the amount of content in each row been changed) almost shows the desirable behaviour, when the contentrow has lots of content; i.e. it should swallow up the after row:

https://codepen.io/ddd2347823457823782378/pen/MWgVKJR

I don't want the scrollbar at the side there, though. Our first choice is for it to also shrink the before row, but *only* in the case when it has completely swallowed up the after row. If that is impossible, I want the scrollbar to only appear on the individual cell.

As requested here is the HTML, followed by CSS, from the codepen. I've elided the dummy text, so it is readable (but in fact you can still see the problem: the `before` row text is at the top of its cell, not at the bottom).

```
<div class="twocol">
  <div class="before" class="left">
    Lorem ipsum...
  </div>
  <div class="before" class="right">
    寒長局真経給南...
  </div>
  <div class="contentrow" class="left">
    53rv3s c0mm4ndz...
  </div>
  <div class="contentrow" class="right">
    <textarea>Please translate that gibberish into English here...
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="after" class="left">
    Unu aj pago komplika...
  </div>
  <div class="after" class="right">
    ろ舳離差のろエヤカミツ...
</div>
```

```
textarea {width:100%;height:100%;min-height:3rem;font-size:1.2rem;}
.twocol {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 35% auto 1fr;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100vh - 3.1rem);
}

.before {overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;}
.contentrow {font-size:1.2rem;vertical-align:top;}
.after {overflow:hidden;vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: Add your [mcve] in your question, not codepen.

Comment: So you're saying the top containers should have the content start at the bottom instead of the top? That would mean that you would have to ( theorhetically ) scroll up to the content if there was a scroll bar in the container?

Comment: @j08691 Done! All the CSS questions I've looked at (and I've read hundreds the past week!), seem to get ignored if they don't have a codepen, so I tried to get that right, then forgot the basics. Sorry!

Comment: @Keith Yes, exactly: if the scrollbar was there, I expect the scrollbar thumb to be at the bottom, not at the top. (But, also when there is only a little content, and no overflow/scrollbar, the content should show at the bottom of the container, not at the top.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix, now, for both issues.

For the main issue, getting it to overflow out of the top: use a nested div, where the outer one has `postition:relative`, then the inner one has `position: absolute;bottom:0`. So the HTML changed to this:

```
<div class="twocol">
  <div class="before">
    <div class="left">
      Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="before">
    <div class="right">
      寒長局真経給南...
    </div>
  </div>

  ...the other two rows unchanged...

</div>
```

And the CSS changes were replacing:

```
.before {overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;}
```

with:

```
.before {position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.before .left {position:absolute;bottom:0;}
.before .right {position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

(Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/20807193/841830, so it looks like a more general trick, not just for grid. I still don't know if there is some more direct way to configure a grid to behave like this, without needing to nest divs.)

And for the second issue, of wanting vertical scrollbars on each individual cell, not on the whole page, it was simply a matter of putting `overflow:hidden` on the grid, and then `overflow-y: auto` on the `.contentrow`.

(I also adding a bit of padding on .contentrow, otherwise the textarea got scrollbars when it didn't need them.... Oh, just noticed that only worked in Firefox, not in Chrome, but it might just be a matter of tweaking the padding/margin?)

The codepen showing both changes together is at: https://codepen.io/ddd2347823457823782378/pen/pozLavz